# Does a "make-table query" ever delete anything in Microsoft Access?

Tags: microsoft-access

When I use a query to make a new table, does that data get deleted from the old table when it is put in the new table, or is it duplicated so that a copy of the data is now on both tables? I partly wonder because Access warns you when trying to do this, but if Access is just making a new table and not deleting anything, why is a warning needed? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you use
Select attr1, attr2, ... Into Mytable
From ...;

both, Mytable and all data in Mytable will be deleted. Your old data will not be kept (duplicated).

If you would like to keep your "old" data, then you should write

Insert Into Mytable (attr1, attr2, ...)
Select attr1, attr2, ...
From ...;

Hope this helps.

Rainer